# How to Change PHPMailer class to normal Mail

Tags: php, email

I am having problems sending emails using the PHPMailer class for my registration form.  I was wondering if the below code could be changed into a normal Mail class please.

```html
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1/PHPMailer.php');

class Email {

 public $objUrl;
 private $objMailer;

 public function __construct($objUrl = null) {
 
  $this->objUrl = is_object($objUrl) ? $objUrl : new Url();
  
  $this->objMailer = new PHPMailer();
  $this->objMailer->IsSMTP();
  $this->objMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
  $this->objMailer->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
  $this->objMailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $this->objMailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $this->objMailer->Port = 465;
  $this->objMailer->Username = "email here";
  $this->objMailer->Password = "password here";
  $this->objMailer->SetFrom("email here", "name here");
  $this->objMailer->AddReplyTo("email here ", "name here");
  
  
  
 }

 public function process($case = null, $array = null) {
 
  if (!empty($case)) {
  
   switch($case) {
    
    case 1:
    
    // add url to the array
    $link  = "<a href=\"";
    $link .= SITE_URL.$this->objUrl->href('activate', array('code', $array['hash']));
    $link .= "\">";
    $link .= SITE_URL.$this->objUrl->href('activate', array('code', $array['hash']));
    $link .= "</a>";
    $array['link'] = $link;
    
    $this->objMailer->Subject = "Activate your account";
    
    $this->objMailer->MsgHTML($this->fetchEmail($case, $array));
    $this->objMailer->AddAddress(
     $array['email'], 
     $array['first_name'].' '.$array['last_name']
    );
    
    break;
    
   }
   
   
   // send email
   if ($this->objMailer->Send()) {
    $this->objMailer->ClearAddresses();
    return true;
   }
   return false;
   
  
  }
 
 
 }

 public function fetchEmail($case = null, $array = null) {
 
  if (!empty($case)) {
   
   if (!empty($array)) {   
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
     ${$key} = $value;
    }   
   }
   
   ob_start();
   require_once(EMAILS_PATH.DS.$case.".php");
   $out = ob_get_clean();
   return $this->wrapEmail($out);
  
  }
 
 }

 public function wrapEmail($content = null) {
  if (!empty($content)) {
   return "<div style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:21px;\">{$content}</div>";
  }
 }
 



}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

I have tried to amend the code to the below code but all I get is a blank screen.  I have checked on firefox and no error messages are displayed.  Can anyone help fix the problem.

Thank you

```html
<?php

//require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1/PHPMailer.php');

class Email {

 public $objUrl;
 //private $objMailer;

 public function __construct($objUrl = null) {
 
  $this->objUrl = is_object($objUrl) ? $objUrl : new Url();
  
  $to = "qakbar26@gmail.com";
  $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: qakbar26@gmail.com";
  
  
  
 }

 public function process($case = null, $array = null) {
 
  if (!empty($case)) {
  
   switch($case) {
    
    case 1:
    
    // add url to the array
    $link  = "<a href=\"";
    $link .= SITE_URL.$this->objUrl->href('activate', array('code', $array['hash']));
    $link .= "\">";
    $link .= SITE_URL.$this->objUrl->href('activate', array('code', $array['hash']));
    $link .= "</a>";
    $array['link'] = $link;
    
    $subject = "Activate your account";
    
    $message($this->fetchEmail($case, $array));
    $address(
     $array['email'], 
     $array['first_name'].' '.$array['last_name']
    );
    
    break;
    
   }
   
   
   // send email
   if ($send()) {
    $this->ClearAddresses();
    return true;
   }
   return false;
   
  
  }
 
 
 }

 public function fetchEmail($case = null, $array = null) {
 
  if (!empty($case)) {
   
   if (!empty($array)) {   
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
     ${$key} = $value;
    }   
   }
   
   ob_start();
   require_once(EMAILS_PATH.DS.$case.".php");
   $out = ob_get_clean();
   return $this->wrapEmail($out);
  
  }
 
 }

 public function wrapEmail($content = null) {
  if (!empty($content)) {
   return "<div style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333;line-height:21px;\">{$content}</div>";
  }
 }
 



}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is *not* a code translation service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself** and then if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working**.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update I have manged to get the PHPMailer ot work after I commented out the below line of code.

```html
$this->objMailer->IsSMTP();
```

Not sure why but the `IsSMTP();` is not letting the emails go through.